# Databinding and RecyclerView in android app

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I'm wondering how to make `Databinding` and `RecyclerView` work together. I have an adapter class defined as follows:

```
public class RestaurantRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RestaurantRecyclerViewAdapter.BindingHolder> {

    private RestaurantsListViewModel mDataContext;

    public RestaurantRecyclerViewAdapter(RestaurantsListViewModel vm) {
        mDataContext = vm;
    }


    @Override
    public BindingHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_restaurant_list_item, parent, false);
        BindingHolder holder = new BindingHolder(v);

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final BindingHolder holder, int position) {
        final RestaurantListItemViewModel restaurant = mDataContext.getRestaurant(position);

        holder.getBinding().setVariable(BR.restaurant, restaurant);
        holder.getBinding().executePendingBindings();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataContext.getRestaurantsCount();
    }

    public class BindingHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ViewDataBinding binding;

        public BindingHolder(View rowView) {
            super(rowView);
            binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(rowView);
        }

        public ViewDataBinding getBinding() {
            return binding;
        }

    }

}
```

If `RestaurantListViewModel` gets updated with some new restaurants I'd like the `RecyclerView` to re-render these new objects. How can I accomplish that?

**EDIT:**

@Vladimirs approach seems sensible, however I'm having trouble implementing the `onBindViewHolder` method:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final RestaurantListItemViewModel restaurant = restaurants.get(position);

    holder.getBinding().setVariable(BR.restaurant, restaurant);
    holder.getBinding().executePendingBindings();
}
```

Now there's no `getBinding` method.

Answer (score 4):

You could create adapter first

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapters {

    @BindingAdapter("items")
    public static void setItems(RecyclerView view, List<Object> items) {
        RecyclerView.Adapter<?> adapter = view.getAdapter();
        if (adapter instanceof RestaurantRecyclerViewAdapter) {
            // tell RestaurantRecyclerViewAdapter to set new list of items
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("RecyclerView.Adapter is not RestaurantRecyclerViewAdapter");
        }
    }
}
```

then in the view model

```
public final ObservableList<Object> items = new ObservableArrayList<>();
```

and finally in xml layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:items="@{viewModel.items}"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"/>
```

It is pretty simple way which does not account partial changes of items, you can take look more into [ObservableList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableList.html) and [OnListChangedCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableList.OnListChangedCallback.html)

**UPD**
As follow up on OnListChangedCallback, I thought may be something like this could be implemented with a adapter to react on exact changes of the list.

```
public class ObservableListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    ObservableList<Object> list;

    ObservableList.OnListChangedCallback<ObservableList<Object>> callback = new ObservableList.OnListChangedCallback<ObservableList<Object>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(ObservableList<Object> sender) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeChanged(ObservableList<Object> sender, int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            notifyItemRangeChanged(positionStart, itemCount);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeInserted(ObservableList<Object> sender, int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            notifyItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeMoved(ObservableList<Object> sender, int fromPosition, int toPosition, int itemCount) {
            notifyItemRangeRemoved(fromPosition, itemCount);
            notifyItemRangeInserted(toPosition, itemCount);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeRemoved(ObservableList<Object> sender, int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            notifyItemRangeRemoved(positionStart, itemCount);
        }
    };

    public ObservableListAdapter(@NonNull ObservableList<Object> list) {
        this.list = list;
        this.list.addOnListChangedCallback(callback);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Where should I put the `setItems` method?

Comment: In any class you would like to. I have created a class called RecyclerViewAdapters and put the function there. I tried myself now, see updated second part of the question. It works like a charm, no need for xml, just pass your ObservableList to constructor.

Comment: Next question - I need to override method `onBindViewHolder` however I don't know how to do this using your approach. Take a look at my updated question.

Comment: I don't know how to implement your solution :). I've copied your `Adapter` code, I'm passing the adapter an `ObservableList`, but the compiler complains with the error saying: `Error:(2) No resource identifier found for attribute 'items' in package 'com.mypackage'`

Comment: It is regular RecyclerView Adapter, how to use it, would be a separate question.

Comment: You still can use your BindingHolder with no problem.